# Sum numbers in multiple different files

Tags: bash, awk, sum

I'm looking for the most efficient way to sum `X` columns of floats, each column is stored in a distinct file.

All files have exactly the same number of lines (a few hundred).
I do not know in advance the number `X`.

Example with `X=3`:

File1:

```
0.5
0
...
```

File2:

```
0
1.5
...
```

File3:

```
1.1
2
...
```

I'd like to generate a file, say `sum_files`:

```
1.6
3.5
...
```

Any efficient way to do this in awk or bash? (There exist solutions using adhoc python scripts, but I'm wondering how this can be done in awk or bash.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read one line from each file and join them with a delimiter, this is one of the things `paste(1)` does well. Pass the result on to `bc(1)` to get the sums:

```
paste -d+ file1 file2 file3 | bc -l
```

Output:

```
1.6
3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK`'s `FNR` [built-in variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html) for this task following way:

```
awk '{arr[FNR]+=$1}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i+=1){print arr[i]}}' file1 file2 file3
```

Explanation: for each line do increase value in array `arr` under key being number of line in file by value of 1st field. After processing all files `print` values stored in `arr`. Note that `FNR` might be used in `for` as limit due to fact that all files have equal number of lines.